# MySQL SELECT WHERE = 1649972899018952705 returns '1649972899018952706' | MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

today's story is that I got some wrong results and then I found out the reason after spending the whole day.

The reason is that I am trying to use a BIGINT id to equal to a VARCHAR(64) id.

The wrong SQL is:

```
select t1.id,t1.name,
       t2.id,t2.name
from location t1
     left join location t2 on t2.parent_id = t1.id
where id = 1649972899018952705
```

I don't know who create this table, but the truth is that the type of id is BIGINT, and the type of parent_id is VARCHAR(64).

But why? I have tried these:

```
select 1649972899018952705 = '1649972899018952706' # returns 1 
select  164997289901895270 = '164997289901895271'  # returns 1 
select  164997289901895271 = '164997289901895261'  # returns 1 
select   16499728990189527 = '164997289901895261'  # returns 0
select  164997289901895271 = '16499728990189526'   # returns 0
select   16499728990189527 = '16499728990189526'   # returns 0
select                   1 = '2'                   # returns 0
```

I guess MySQL will change the type of '1649972899018952706' or 1649972899018952705 to operate, but how does the parameters be changed, and it seems like MySQL will truncate them.

And can I get different results by using different MySQL versions?

Comment: Truncation will always happen with fixed-precision numbers, either integer or floating point, simply because beyond a certain point there is no room to store the difference. This doesn't happen just in MySQL, but in any programming language. For exact results you probably need to use a type with enough precision, such as `DECIMAL`, and to avoid any ambiguity, also perform explicit type casting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.7 (as well as in MySQL 8.0) the arguments for the compare operator do get converted to floating point (double precision), when one argument is string and the other is numeric, as defined in [12.3 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison operations:
>
> - [...]
> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (double-precision) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point numbers.

So it is like calling `CAST(value AS DOUBLE)` (in MySQL 8.0) on the arguments and compare them afterwards. See the following result when explicit use the `CAST()` function:

```
SELECT CAST(1649972899018952705 AS DOUBLE), CAST('1649972899018952706' AS DOUBLE), CAST(1649972899018952705 AS DOUBLE) = CAST('1649972899018952706' AS DOUBLE);
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(1649972899018952705 AS DOUBLE) | CAST('1649972899018952706' AS DOUBLE) | CAST(1649972899018952705 AS DOUBLE) = CAST('1649972899018952706' AS DOUBLE) |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               1.6499728990189527e18 |                 1.6499728990189527e18 |                                                                           1 |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The documentation also mention a solution, where you can cast one argument to `UNSIGNED`:

> (...) One way to avoid such problems is to use CAST() so that a value is not converted implicitly to a float-point number:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT CAST('9223372036854775807' AS UNSIGNED) = 9223372036854775806;
>         -> 0
> ```

So you can use the `CAST()` function like this in your query:

```
select t1.id,t1.name,
       t2.id,t2.name
from location t1
     left join location t2 on CAST(t2.parent_id AS UNSIGNED) = t1.id
where id = 1649972899018952705
```

Comment: Thank you. I temporarily used CAST to achieve my purpose before modifying the table structure.