Implicit Type Conversion in MySQL
Why is the result of this query 1 instead of 0?
select 10000000000198285 = '10000000000198283';

After using the CAST() function for type conversion, the result is 0.
Please answer MySQL's implicit conversion rules for bigint types
MySQL version：8.0.39

You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76188143/mysql-select-where-1649972899018952705-returns-1649972899018952706-mysql-5
